# Emacs: keep cursor column automatically when move up/down (add spaces if required)

Tags: emacs, cursor

Imagine I'm editing this text:

`this is my long line|
short line
this is my other long line`

How can I keep cursor on current column when moving up and down (this is common behavour for many text editors)?

Like in picture-mode but without other features (for example when C-e is pressing cursor should be moved to the actual end of line)

PS This question looks like duplicate to others but probably isn't.

Upd1: The artist-mode and picture-mode  has problems:

- add extra spaces when I move cursor beyond the end-of-line (and document became to be "modified". Not cool)
- C-e actually not moves cursor to the end of line
- cursor movement works with surprices in visual-line-mode (for example not moved to the "previous "part" of the long line

Upd2: set-goal-column is cool but not understood which way it could be used. I just want to move cursor visually down from current column position where cursor is.

Answer (score 1):

Using `set-goal-column` still causes the cursor to change columns to match the end of shorter lines when moving up and down.

You might give `artist-mode` a try. It seemed to match your requirements in handling end of line correctly, along with other cursor movement, but keeps the same column adding spaces as necessary when moving up or down.

Answer (score 1):

Here an answer near to request. It doesn't insert spaces just to reach a certain column - may you tell a use-case for this?

```
(defvar ar-move-line-this-column nil)

(defun ar-move-line-keep-column-intern (arg)
  (unless (eq last-command this-command)
    (setq ar-move-line-this-column (current-column)))
  (forward-line arg)
  (while (and (not (eolp)) (< (current-column) ar-move-line-this-column))
    (forward-char 1)))

(defun ar-forward-line-keep-column (&optional arg)
  "Go to current column of next line.

If line is shorter, go to end of line"
  (interactive "p")
  (ar-move-line-keep-column-intern (or arg 1)))

(defun ar-backward-line-keep-column (&optional arg)
  "Go to current column of line above.

If line is shorter, go to end of line"
  (interactive "p")
  (ar-move-line-keep-column-intern (- arg)))
```

Answer (score 0):

`set-goal-column`, bound to <kbd>C-x C-n</kbd> will set the current column as the target column when moving up or down.

You can cancel this feature with a prefix argument <kbd>C-u C-x C-n</kbd>.

Documentation [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Moving-Point.html).

Answer (score 0):

The quarter-plane-mode was also suggested as close solution